# How does CMake's export know what version the target is?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am trying to make a library. My CMakeLists.txt looks something like this:

```
add_library(Lib STATIC)
set_target_properties(Lib PROPERTIES
    VERSION 0.1)
export(TARGETS Lib
    FILE ${BIN_DIR}/LibConfig.cmake)
```

When an outside project uses this library, CMake shows the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Lib" that is
  compatible with requested version "0.1".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

some directory/Lib/bin/LibConfig.cmake, version: unknown
```

Looking at the generated LibConfig.cmake, nothing is wrong except that it doesn't carry the version information.

Comment: What's your CMake version?

Comment: @StanleyF.  My CMake version is 3.11.2 but I'm using `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)`

Answer (score 1):

To allow CMake determining the version of your library, you need to create a `LibConfigVersion.cmake` file.

An example can be found in the CMake documentation: [generating package files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#example-generating-package-files)

For your library, this results in something like this:

```
add_library(Lib STATIC)
set_target_properties(Lib PROPERTIES VERSION 0.1)
export(TARGETS LibFILE ${BIN_DIR}/LibConfig.cmake)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(${BIN_DIR}/LibConfigVersion.cmake
                                 VERSION 0.1
                                 COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)
```

Instead of providing the version information multiple times, you may set it once in the `project` command:

```
project(Lib VERSION 0.1)
```